# debugging react-native TextInput behaviour

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am adding simple date masking to my react-native app. It works, it seems in rnplay at https://rnplay.org/apps/3twbCw and it is not working with my app.

The masking function is:

```
dateFormat(text) {
  if (text.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    text += '/';
  } else if (text.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    text += '/';
  }
  this.setState({birthdate: text});
}
```

I apply/call this function as:

```
<TextInput
  key='birthdateTxt'
  style={styles.formField}
  returnKeyType='done'
  ref={(ref) => this.birthdateInput = ref}
  onFocus={() => this.inputFocused(this.birthdateInput)}
  value={this.state.birthdate}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.dateFormat(text)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.register()}
/>
```

The function is invoked. This is clear from the debug output. However this.setState({birthdate: text}) does not alter the value of the TextInput. The rnplay sample seems to be doing the same thing, yet it does not exhibit the same problem.

What do I check?

Comment: this problem is happening with an App build on 0.17 and rnplay runs on 0.13rc. that's the only possible cause that i noticed, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextInput is apparently partially broken in 0.17.